# Angular 10 - ViewChild MatTable nativelement is undefined

Tags: angular

I have a MatTable and I need to know the width of table after rendering.

```
<table mat-table 
    #logtable
    [dataSource]="dataSource" 
    id="log-table" 
    class="mat-elevation-z1" 
    multiTemplateDataRows
```

> 

I usually use ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('logtable', { static: false })    table : ElementRef;
```

The "table" property is correctly set and its type is MatTable that not have "nativelement" (that is undefined).

Trying to access _elementRef.nativelement in console, seems work unfortunally Angualar doesnt compile if trying to do the same in the code.

How can I access clientWidth property?

[image]

Comment: Can't you get it with `window.innerWidth`?

Comment: I need the table width, not entire page width

Comment: Okay. Does your html code has any `*ngIf` in any div around the table? Could you provide the code from the whole HTML and ts?

Comment: It seems like Angular cast the ElementRef to MatTable preventing me to access to nativeElement directly (and there is no get method). I have solved with a DIV above the table. In this case nativeElement is where is espected with real offsetWith value.